# PHP embeded in HTML not working properly

Tags: php, html

I am trying to embed php in css but the result is not as required it is showing me the variable names and an echo statement:-

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
require_once("mysqlconnect.php");
session_start();
$q="select * from profile where mobile=8078899386";
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
    <?php
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$q);
        $field=mysqli_fetch_field($result);
        echo "<p>$result</p>";
        echo "<p>$field</p>";
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Result is:

```
$result
"; echo "
$field

"; ?>
```

Comment: php not work with `.html` extension directly . change the extension to `.php`

Comment: yes i did the same saved it with .php

Comment: Do one thing, just create one <p> or <div> by using php and check if its working or not. Then comes to this looping and all

Comment: html is working fine, i tried but it still shows the echo and stuff.

Comment: try to concat your PHP variables when you are printing it.

Comment: @Anant nothing prints

Comment: yes thanks php wasn't working.....

Comment: @KratiChaturvedi  you have a lot of answer on your previous questions in pending states(not marked yet). If you got the answer for them then mark those answer.It will help others .Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change like below

```
 echo "<p>".$result."</p>";
 echo "<p>".$field."</p>";
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server-side scripting language, so you have to save the file with the php extension (e.g. *filename.php*) and the script has to be executed from the server-side. Your output comes from the client-side (i.e. HTML output).